# Expect is not working if used after calling shell script

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I have shell script test have below content:

```
read -s -n 1 -p "press enter to continue..." key
if [[ $key = "" ]]; then
    echo 'You pressed enter!'
else
    echo "You pressed '$key'"
fi
```

I am calling above script with below script. But when i execute below script then it hangs at input level

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
spawn ./test.sh
expect "Press enter to continue..."
send "\r"
EOF
```

Comment: learn to use http://shellcheck.net **before** you post your code here ;-) . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER:
You forgot a `then` in your if statement.

BTW:
You can use `REPLY` variable like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -r -n 1 -p "press enter to continue..."
if [[ $REPLY = "" ]] ; then
    echo 'You pressed enter!'
else
    echo "You pressed '$REPLY'"
fi
```

Comment: then got missed during typing. I am calling shell script A from shell script B. Shell script A requires user input during execution. So i want to use expect for providing user input.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by using `expect`? Your script should work if you add `then` after as in my example..